# Conjugation in special linear group and field extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-groups

Let $E/F$ be a field extension, if two matrixs $A,B$ in $SL_n(F)$ are conjugated in $SL_n(E)$. Can we conclude they are conjugated in $SL_n(F)$? If not, can we construct counterexamples for every base field $F$? What will happen for other linear algebraic groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Take for example
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&\sqrt2\\-\frac1{\sqrt2}&0\end{pmatrix},\ \ B=\begin{pmatrix}0&-\sqrt2\\\frac1{\sqrt2}&0\end{pmatrix}\in\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb R)$$

Then since $A$ and $B$ have the same eigenvalues, they are conjugate in $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb C)$, and in fact $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb C)$. But they are not conjugate in $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb R)$: it's straightforward to check that any matrix $P\in\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb R)$ with $PA = BP$ must be of the form
$$\begin{pmatrix}a&2c\\c&-a\end{pmatrix}$$
which can't possibly be in $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb R)$. A similar example should work for other quadratic extensions $F/E$.

The obstruction comes from Galois cohomology. I'm not so fluent in this, but here is the key point. Assume that $E/F$ is Galois. If $G$ is an algebraic group and $M\in G(F)$ (maybe satisfying some conditions?), there is a bijection between the $G(F)$ conjugacy classes of $M$ which become conjugate in $G(E)$ and
$$\ker \big(H^1(\mathrm{Gal}(E/F), Z_G(M)(E)))\to H^1(\mathrm{Gal}(E/F), G(E)\big),$$
where $Z_G(M)(E)$ are the elements of $G(E)$ which commute with $M$.

[These notes](https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~berhuy/fichiers/NTUcourse.pdf) contain an introduction to Galois cohomology, with the motivating example being exactly your problem.